# Tasker: Create calender event if sms contains 'Yes'

Tags: applications, tasker, automation

Every Wednesday i sent a sms with Tasker to confirm a appointment on Thursday the appointment is always at the same place and time.

Is there a way with Tasker to create a Calendar appointment if the reply sms contains yes?

Thanks, hope you can help!

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can

**Task**

- Create a new task "New Task + "
- You can name this Task *CalAppointment* or anything.
- Click "+" to add new Action
- App >> Calender Insert [**In/For**: *the number of minutes from now at which the calendar entry should start. Optionally, For how many minutes the calendar entry should last*); **Calender** (*choose the target calendar app*) **Title**: (Optional): **Description** (optional); **Location** (Optional); **Available** (if not clicked the entry is marked as busy)]
- Tap back to exit from this task
- Save this task and exit

**Profile (or Trigger)**

Create a Profile which allows triggering received SMS and day:

- Goto Profiles Tab and click the "+"
- Event >> Phone >> Received Text
- [Type: SMS;  Sender: Choose the number of the sender; Content: *Yes *
- Tap back to exit from this window
- Long press on first context and choose "Add +"
- Day >> Select Week Day (scroll down the on the arrow under Days) and choose Wednesday